# Is there a way to pass a function call to an inner object?

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to pass a function call to an inner object, maybe through a decorator or wrapper?  In the example below, class A holds a list of class B objects, and one of the class B objects is selected as the active object.  I want class A to function as a passthrough, just identifying which of the class B objects that the call goes to.  However, class A doesn't know what type of class it is going to hold beforehand, so I can't just add a set_var function to class A.  It has to work for any generic function that class B has.  It will only have one type of class in its objects list, so it could take class B as an input when it is instantiated and dynamically create functions, if that's a possibility.  The client wouldn't know whether it's dealing with class A or class B.  The code below is as far as I got.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = []
        self.current_object = 0

    def add_object(self, object):
        self.objects.append(object)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10

    def set_var(self, new_var):
        self.var = new_var

a_obj = A()
b_obj1 = B()
b_obj2 = B()
a_obj.add_object(b_obj1)
a_obj.add_object(b_obj2)

a_obj.set_var(100)
```

Comment: Look up "proxy class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the generic `__getattr__` to delegate to the wrapped object.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.objects = []
        self.current_object = 0

    def add_object(self, obj):
        self.objects.append(obj)
        self.current_object = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.current_object, name)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10

    def set_var(self, new_var):
        self.var = new_var

a_obj = A()
b_obj1 = B()
b_obj2 = B()
a_obj.add_object(b_obj1)
a_obj.add_object(b_obj2)

a_obj.set_var(100)
print(b_obj2.var)
```

That will print "100".

You will still get an `AttributeError` if the wrapped object doesn't have the expected method.

Answer (score 0):

It was interesting to look at this, it is intentionally rough but it does indeed allow you to call one the B instance's `set_var` methods.

The code below uses sets as a quick and dirty way to see the difference in callable methods, and if there is; it sets the attribute based on that name. Binding the method to the A instance.

This would only bind set_var once from the first object given.

```
def add_object(self, object):
        self.objects.append(object)
        B_methods = set([m for m in dir(object) if callable(getattr(object, m))])
        A_methods = set([m for m in dir(self) if callable(getattr(self, m))])
        to_set = B_methods.difference(A_methods)
        for method in to_set:
            setattr(self, method, getattr(object, method))
```